# Get a specific Rule ID in a GPO

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, gpo

i am currently working on Windows Active Directory, and i would like to know if it's possible to get the id of a rule defined in a GPO. Because i would like write some `powershell` scripts to check if some rules are activated or not. I've found out that it was linked into the registers but only for the current user but i don't want to run my script for every user but only on the server domain or domain administrator account.

For example i've written a GPO telling that every basic user should not have the right to use the task manager i can get a report on my GPO containing list of users which are submitted to this rule, GPOID, and other information but no information about the rule except its name which is in this case "Disable TaskMgr"

Answer (score 0):

The [`Get-GPO` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461059.aspx), which is part of the [Group Policy cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), appears to return a GUID that it calls an ID as well as a status.

Comment: It's the GPO's UID called GPOID, that's not what i want, i want id of rule inside a GPO

Comment: @VincentNAHMIAS To the best of my knowledge individual rules don't have IDs at all.  GPOs aren't structured that way.  I mean, browse to your SYSVOL folder and take a look.  You can run `Get-GPOReport -Name 'Disable TaskMgr' -Path .\GPOReport.xml -ReportType Xml` to get a pretty comprehensive report of the GPO and then query it with XQuery or XPath using `Select-Xml` or by converting the output to `[xml]` and calling the relevant method.  You should be able to use that to determine if a rule is active or not.